# Why am i not able to append the list correctly?

Tags: python

what i want to do:
I am asking user to input the name of the student and their score:

My code:

```
master_pair=[]
pair=[]
b=int(input())
for i in range(b):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    pair.append(name)
    pair.append(score)
    print("pair")
    print(pair)
    print("master_pair")
    print(master_pair)
    master_pair.append(pair)
    print("master_pair")
    print(master_pair)
    pair.clear()
    print("pair")
    print(pair)
```

What I am expecting:
lets say i enter the value of b(3rd line of above code) as 2.
and enter name as "a" & score as 1 for the first iteration, followed by name as "b" & score as 2 for the second iteration.
so the output that i expect is:
[["a",1.0],["b",2]]

what I'm getting instead is as follows
[[], []]

to understand how the things are working inside the loop, i printed the values of the 2 lists(pair and master_pair) at different stages inside the loop.

following is the output that was printed while the loop was working:

2
a
1
pair
['a', 1.0]
master_pair
[]
master_pair
[['a', 1.0]]
pair
[]
b
2
pair
['b', 2.0]
master_pair
[['b', 2.0]]
master_pair
[['b', 2.0], ['b', 2.0]]
pair
[]

here the value of b is taken as 2. the first name is a, score of a is 1.
the second name is b, score of b is taken as 2.
when i tried to print the value of master_pair after the execution of the loop was completed, i found out that it was empty.

I don't know what is wrong in my understanding.
Please ask for details that is relevant to this question.

Comment: You have added two references to the *same* list.

Comment: `master_pair.append(pair.copy())` to keep data in master pair

Comment: I tried "master_pair.append(pair.copy())" but it isn't helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work perfectly and solve your problem.

```
master_pair=[]
b = int(input("b "))

for i in range(b):
    name = input("name ")
    score = float(input("score "))
    pair = [] # brought it in
    pair.append(name)
    pair.append(score)
    print("pair")
    print(pair)
    print("master_pair")
    print(master_pair)
    master_pair.append(pair) 
    print("master_pair")
    print(master_pair)
```

- we bring pair in so we don't have to use clear() (its more better, i think this way)

Comment: Thanks Hisham, the code that you gave seems to work perfectly fine. Kindly also explain me the concept behind this in detail(I'm new to coding). also if we are using pair = [] in every iteration, whats the point of clearing it?

Comment: @akshaydaga I just edited my answer you can see reason. And you can always choose this answer as best.

Comment: 1, The code seems to work, even when i don't use copy. (why are you suggesting me to use it?) 2.  setting pair to an empty list by using clear is also logically correct. My question is why is my code not working?. No doubt your suggestion is working but it doesn't answer the 2 questions that i have

Comment: @akshaydaga yes you are right, I was blind that I saw ```master_pair``` output as just repeating pair which we had entered.

Comment: I definitely get your way of thinking. what is wrong in using clear? even that seems to be logically correct. why my code gives a wrong output when i use clear?

Comment: @akshaydaga . when you append list is stored like this in a list for e.g ```master_pair = [pair]```. After it print statement comes which prints ```pair``` value and at end of loop this pair is cleared too. I hope you understand know. Please let me know if you have other queries.

Comment: Sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new list each time:

```
master_pair = []
b = int(input())
for i in range(b):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    pair = [name, score]
    master_pair.append(pair)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your answer. The code that you gave seems to be working. But can you explain the mistake that i did and what made you recommend me to create a new list every time (moreover what does it mean to create a new list every time)? I'm new to python. please pardon me for the silly questions that i am asking.